# Конвертация string во float в JavaScript/Vue.js

Tags: javascript, строки, vue.js

Фронт пишется на **vue.js**
На входе есть строковая переменная (денежная величина), которая приходит с бэка. Пытаюсь ее конвертировать во float, но конвертации не происходит. Ниже небольшой пример кода

// Так как нет возможности предоставить код серверной части, присвою значение переменной

```
let back_end_value = '0.012';
let local_value = 10;
let tmp = 0;
let variable = 0;
```

Проверяю типы:

```
console.log('BACK: ', typeof(back_end_value)); // String
console.log('local_value: ', typeof(local_value)); // Integer
```

Все правильно. так и должно быть. Теперь конвертирую строковую величину в десятичное значение, и снова проверяю тип

```
variable = parseFloat(back_end_value).toFixed(8); //Мне нужны 8 знаков после запятой
console.log('BACK: ', typeof(variable)); // String
```

Снова получаю тип String. Как такое может быть?

В результате при сложении вижу вот такой результат:

```
tmp = local_value + back_end_value
console.log('Result: ', temp); // 10.0.0012
```

Подскажите, где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что [toFixed возвращает строку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), а не "десятичное значение"

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!!! Вы очень помогли!